# Where is the software icon?

Tags: 19.04

I used to use Ubuntu 16 when my old computer died. I bought a new computer and installed Ubuntu 19. I can't find the access to the app repository, the icon for which used to be right at the top of my U-16 menu. Where can I find it? Or for that matter, all the apps I used to have before the crash, especially Freecell and photo editing. Thanks!

Comment: There is not Ubuntu 16, there is Ubuntu Core 16, though I suspect you mean Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with the Unity 7 desktop.  Ubuntu 19.04 reaches EOL this month (19.04 is not a long-term-support release) so if you just installed it, I'd recommend re-install Ubuntu 19.10; or release-upgrade to 19.10 but a re-install will be faster). The default desktop for Ubuntu 19.04/19.10 is GNOME so it a little different. You can add 'Unity 7' to your system so it's close to what you had (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=ubuntu-unity&searchon=names)

Comment: Also note you'll need to enable the 'universe' repository (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) as by default Ubuntu only uses Canonical supported software, enabling 'universe' enables community software to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You have  "ubuntu software" icon standard, and  you can install from terminal  "synaptic". (sudo apt-get install synaptic).

For more Dock customization options we can use dconf-editor. dconf-editor is not installed by default but you can install it by openning up a terminal and entering the following linux command:

$ sudo apt install dconf-tools

Next, navigate to: org->gnome->shell->extensions->dash-to-dock schema. Feel free to browse and play with any settings available on this page to customize your Dock panel.